# Why does Grails appear to be saving my invalid domain object?

Tags: grails, grails-orm

I am using Grails 2.4.2. I'm saving an instance of a domain class that violates the constraints, so I would expect the save to fail. But it appears to succeed. The Grails documentation states:

> Another thing to bear in mind is that Grails validates a domain instance every time you save it. If that validation fails the domain instance will not be persisted to the database.

The domain class:

```
class Book {
    String name
    static constraints = {
        name unique: true
    }
    String toString() { "[Book: id=${id} name=${name}]" }
}
```

The following code modifies a second instance so that it has the same name as the first and tries to save it (book3.save). I expect this to fail, and it does return null. But then I load up the same object by Id (Book.get(book2.id)) and find that it has the new name. Finally, it prints the entire list of books, and we see that they both have the same name.

```
    def book1 = new Book(name: "Cats").save()
    def book2 = new Book(name: "Dogs").save()
    log.info "The books: ${Book.list()}"
    def book3 = Book.get(book2.id)
    book3.name = "Cats"
    def book3save = book3.save() // Should fail?
    def book4 = Book.get(book2.id)
    log.info "The result of saving book ${book2.id} with name 'Cats' is ${book3save}"
    log.info "The book with ID ${book2.id} is now named ${book4.name}"
    log.info "The books are: ${Book.list()}"
```

The output:

```
The books: [[Book: id=1 name=Cats], [Book: id=2 name=Dogs]]
The result of saving book 2 with name 'Cats' is null
The book with ID 2 is now named Cats
The books are: [[Book: id=1 name=Cats], [Book: id=2 name=Cats]]
```

Answer (score 0):

Grails will not throw exceptions on validation errors by default.  You can do

```
book3.save(failOnError: true)
```

which will throw an exception.

or you need to check the return value of save().  A null means the validation failed.  You can also do a book3.validate() to see if the instance is valid before attempting a save.

I think what you are seeing in the appearance of the book being updated is due to the hibernate session.  Your save failed but a call to Book.get() loads the instance from the current hibernate session not the database.  If you check the dirty flag you can confirm this checking isDirty() or call refresh() to refetch the instance from the database.